# Nextjs with tailwind takes 8 - 16 seconds to complie

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind for the very first time and using tailwind with nextjs gives very slow compilation time in development mode.

I can confirm this is happening by using tailwind just because if i remove

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

it gives a compilation time in ms.

I have tried using their jit and splitting the css file aswell, nothing seems to be working for me. How can i fix this.

[image: This is my global.css file]

[image: This is how i am importing in my _app.tsx file]

```
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const { shake } = require("./app/global/configStore/tailwind/animations");

module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        shake: { ...shake },
      },
      animation: {
        "error-shake": "shake 0.5s linear",
      },
    },
  },
  content: [
    "./public/*.html",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /(bg|text|border)-./,
    },
  ],
  options: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

I havn't configured anything in postcss.config.js file

and i run my server using yarn run dev.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could consider removing the `safelist` pattern or otherwise look at making the regular expression more strict and match less class candidates.

Comment: @Wongjn That does seem to be an issue for the slow compilation, would you move your comment to an answer? I would like to mark this as an accepted answer. Also if possible would you shed some light on why that is happening ? I would like to know more about this. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider removing the `safelist` pattern or otherwise look at making the regular expression more strict and match less class candidates.

This is because your current `safelist` pattern would match so many class candidates and would generate many rules, thus causing the slow down.

Comment: I can confirm that works, thank you !